# SED Multi-line substitute and hold space

Tags: sed

I had some time to try and learn more SED this week and  have been experiment with the following sample code:

```
    </td>
    <td>
        <h4 class="text-danger" style="display: inline;">**Rádio Club 88 FM**</h4>
        <br>
        <b></b><br>

        <br>Genres: various<!--
        <br><samp>19 http://67.228.135.41:8216/listen.pls shoutcast1 audio/mpeg</samp>
        <div id="jplayer_inspector_19"></div>-->
    </td>
    <td width="120" class="text-right hidden-xs">
        <p>
        24 Listeners<br>
         128 Kbps<br>
        </p>
        <a style="margin:1px" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'tunein', 'playpls', 'http://67.228.135.41:8216/listen.pls');" href="/servers/tools/playlistgenerator/?u=http://67.228.135.41:8216/listen.pls&amp;t=.pls">PLS</a>
        <a style="margin:1px" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'tunein', 'playm3u', 'http://67.228.135.41:8216/listen.pls');" href="/servers/tools/playlistgenerator/?u=http://67.228.135.41:8216/listen.pls&amp;t=.m3u">M3U</a>
        <a style="margin:1px" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'tunein', 'playram', 'http://67.228.135.41:8216/listen.pls');" href="/servers/tools/playlistgenerator/?u=http://67.228.135.41:8216/listen.pls&amp;t=.ram">RAM</a>
        <a style="margin:1px" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" onClick="window.open('/player/?mount=http://67.228.135.41:8216/listen.pls&amp;title=Rádio Club 88 FM&amp;website=http://www.shoutcast.com','PopupPlayer','width=400,height=300'); ga('send', 'event', 'tunein', 'playpopup', 'http://67.228.135.41:8216/listen.pls');" href="#">FLA</a>
    </td>
```

My goal was to have the following outcome which would be parsed from two different line and put back together using the hold space

**Suggested Output**

should  be the the contents of **first match** a **tab** as a seprerator and the **second match**

```
Soundzrise RADIO  \t http://94.23.66.114:8122
::| ([bAm BaM RADIO]) |:: \t http://www.bambamradio.com:8888
NRGRadio.nl \t http://188.138.56.235:27914
```

I have both SED command that work

**First Match**

```
is the H4 line, i am extracting what is between the ">" and "<"  
COMMAND =sed -rne 's/.*<h4 class=.*>(.*)<\/h4>/\1/ip'
```

**Second Match**

```
is the http address in line containing "playpls" - 
Command =  sed -rne "s/.*playpls', '(.*)\/listen.pls'.*/\1/p"
```

My problem is combining then with proper use of the hold space. I have tried  several variations. however none on then have work.  I.e.

```
sed -rne 's/.*<h4 class=.*>(.*)<\/h4>/\1/i;h' -e "s/.*playpls', '(.*)\/listen.pls'.*/\1/;G;p"
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and show the output you expect from your example? The one you show has nothing to do with the input. Also, explain exactly what you are trying to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *must* use `sed` (rather than, say XSLT), or if you just want to better understand how to use hold space, then you'll want to do something like:

Save the `H4` line to hold space:

```
/<h4 /h
```

When you see the `playpls` line, append the hold space:

```
/ 'playpls',/{
G
# do something here
}
```

Now, your pattern space should look something like

```
<a style="margin:1px" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'tunein', 'playpls', 'http://67.228.135.41:8216/listen.pls');" href="/servers/tools/playlistgenerator/?u=http://67.228.135.41:8216/listen.pls&amp;t=.pls">PLS</a>
<h4 class="text-danger" style="display: inline;">**Rádio Club 88 FM**</h4>
```

(including that embedded newline).  So you can replace that comment with something like

```
s/.*'playpls', '\([^']*\)'.*\n.*<h4 [^>]*>\([^<>]*\).*/\2\t\1/p
```

and run your script with `sed -n` so that only the pattern spaces that match the substitution get printed.

In fact, given you'll get no match unless you appended the hold space, you can do all this without braces:

```
#!/bin/sed -rnf
# I've assumed GNU sed above

/<h4 /h
/ 'playpls',/G
/\n/s/.*'playpls', '([^']+)'.*\n.*<h4 [^>]+>([^<>]+).*/\2\t\1/p
```

Comment: Excellent!   so my mistake was that i was trying move the results of each the hold spaces to the pattern space.   rather than combining both lines and then extracting needed elements.  Don't know what my logic assumed that my method would have worked.  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you do some preparatory work for `sed`. Instead of going multi-line at all. `grep` for both lines and then fold them together using `paste`. That gives you lines where both matches are on the same line and not much else. From there it should be easy to pick both references without going multi-line at all.

Example input:

```
# echo 'first_a foo second_A bar first_b junk second_B crap' | tr ' ' '\n'
first_a
foo
second_A
bar
first_b
junk
second_B
crap
```

Work it like this:

```
# echo 'first_a foo second_A bar first_b junk second_B crap' | tr ' ' '\n' | \
    grep -E 'first|second' | \
    paste - -  | \
    sed -e 's/first_\([a-z]*\)[^a-z].*second_\([a-z]*\)/\1 \2/'
a A
b B
```

The point being that the `paste` is a really good tool.